# Could not resolve host error when trying to reproduce Kyma expose function tutorial

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kubernetes, host

I am trying to setup Kyma for my local k3d cluster by following this https://kyma-project.io/docs/kyma/latest/02-get-started/02-deploy-expose-function/ tutorial. Everything seems to work fine up until the final step. My hello-world function shows status RUNNING and the corresponding API rule has status OK.

[Kyma Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgCpz.png)

However, when I click on the host, I only get this:
We can't connect to the server at hello-world.local.kyma.dev.

When I try to access the host through curl, I get "could not resolve host: hello-world.local.kyma.dev".

I did the "export CLUSTER_DOMAIN=local.kyma.dev" command following the quick install guide as well.

I also tried to edit the hosts file but with no success for now.

This happens for me on Windows 10 as well as on Ubuntu, so I am rather lost what to do. Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi kyma-tester-123 welcome to S.F. Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) page. [`*.local.kyma.dev` resolves to 127.0.0.1](https://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php?domain=ANY+server%2Dfault.local.kyma.dev) so your resolver must be broken

Answer (score 0):

For me this helped:

1. Going to my wifi's settings and adding `1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` as DNS in the IPv4 tab and disabling the automatic slider.
2. Reconnecting to wifi.

After this, I get the correct response with
`curl -k https://hello-world.local.kyma.dev:8443`